# How using JOIN to sort table works?

Tags: mysql, join

I'm going through the mysql docs, and under [the common queries section](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-maximum-row.html), they mention how to get the maximum column value of a table by using a LEFT JOIN.  Here's the table:

```
SELECT * FROM shop;

+---------+--------+-------+
| article | dealer | price |
+---------+--------+-------+
|    0001 | A      |  3.45 |
|    0001 | B      |  3.99 |
|    0002 | A      | 10.99 |
|    0003 | B      |  1.45 |
|    0003 | C      |  1.69 |
|    0003 | D      |  1.25 |
|    0004 | D      | 19.95 |
+---------+--------+-------+
```

And here's the query:

```
SELECT s1.article, s1.dealer, s1.price
FROM shop s1
LEFT JOIN shop s2 ON s1.price < s2.price
WHERE s2.article IS NULL;
```

There's several things I can't make heads or tails of.

First, without any `LIMIT 1` statement or ordering (which defeats the purpose of the `JOIN`), I don't understand how it can only return one row (assuming `LEFT JOIN` is a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` that returns all rows in the left table according to [w3 Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp)).

Second, I don't understand the semantics of `s1.price < s2.price`.  Is this saying, "select all rows from `s2` where the statement `s1.price < s2.price` is true (and if so, then w3 schools link above isn't true for mysql)?  I.e. `LEFT JOIN` is a `LEFT INNER JOIN`?

Finally, the `WHERE s2.article IS NULL` makes absolutely no sense to me since each record in the table has an `article` attribute (especially since there's no ambiguous `0000` article).

Comment: the `where s2.article is null` means that (assuming the field is not null), details of s1 will only be found for items where there is not a price higher than it in the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The joining condition `s1.price < s2.price` means that each `s1` row will join with every `s2` row that has a higher price.

This means that for the row in the table `s1` with the highest price (19.95)  no `s2` rows will match. Because it is in an outer join the unmatched `s1` row is returned anyway, but all the `s2` columns will be set to `null`.

The `where s2.article is null` then discards all the rows *except* that one. You may find it informative to inspect the results before that stage with

```
SELECT s1.article,
       s1.dealer,
       s1.price,
       s2.article,
       s2.dealer,
       s2.price
FROM   shop s1
       LEFT JOIN shop s2
         ON s1.price < s2.price;
```

You will see the 1.25 `s1` row joins with 6 `s2` rows, the 10.99 row with one, and the 19.95 one none at all.

Note it is not guaranteed to return only one row, if multiple rows are tied for the highest price all of those will be returned.

Comment: Oh that's genius.  Thanks!